# Copy protected field in subclass constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm trying to subclass a `Connection` object to create an `AuthenticatedConnection`, which should function in the same manner as a `Connection`, with the addition of a token. A straightforward solution is to pass 'wrap' a connection with the subclass constructor.

This solution seems broken, as I cannot access the protected member of a parameter. This means the base constructor cannot be called. Is there a way to implement the constructors so that it is possible to wrap constructors like so?
For example: `new AuthenticatedConnection("token", existingConnection)`

Here is the current (broken) implementation. The compile error is: `Cannot access protected member 'Connection._client' via a qualifier of type 'Connection'; the qualifier must be of type 'AuthenticatedConnection' (or derived from it)`

```
class Connection
{
    // internal details of the connection; should not be public.
    protected object _client;

    // base class constructor
    public Connection(object client) { _client = client; }
}

class AuthenticatedConnection : Connection
{
    // broken constructor?
    public AuthenticatedConnection(string token, Connection connection)
        : base(connection._client)
    {
        // use token etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just set it in the constructor?

Comment: The Decorator pattern might suit your needs (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/479635/UnderstandingplusandplusImplementingplusDecoratorp). Essentially, you want an object that *has* a `Connection` and *is* a `Connection`. It's doable, but you'll have to "forward" all methods that you need for the derived instance to work correctly, and it might get messy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to create a "copying constructor" for the base class:

```
class Connection
{
    // internal details of the connection; should not be public.
    protected object _client;

    // base class constructor
    public Connection(object client) { _client = client; }

    // copying constructor
    public Connection(Connection other) : this(other._client) { }
}

class AuthenticatedConnection : Connection
{
    // broken constructor?
    public AuthenticatedConnection(string token, Connection connection)
        : base(connection)
    {
        // use token etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Re suggested edit: Yes, the popular term appears to be ["copy constructor"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor). There's an MSDN article on [how to implement it in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: d'oh! Yes, a copy constructor is exactly what I was trying to implement, I just didn't think to put it on the base class instead of the subclass. I've kept the copy constructor as `protected`, but everything works as it should now.

Answer (score 0):

> A straightforward solution is to pass 'wrap' a connection with the subclass constructor

This is not straightforward, IMO. The straightforward is this:

```
class AuthenticatedConnection : Connection
{
    public AuthenticatedConnection1(string token, object client)
        : base(client)
    {
        // use token etc
    }
}
```

But if you want to **wrap** the real connection, I'd do it this way:

```
interface IConnection {}
class Connection : IConnection
{
    // internal details of the connection; should not be public.
    protected object _client;

    // base class constructor
    public Connection(object client) { _client = client; }
}

class AuthenticatedConnection : IConnection
{
    private readonly IConnection connection;

    public AuthenticatedConnection2(string token, IConnection connection)
    {
        // use token etc
    }
}
```